# why does viewport 700px not fit 700px website on mobile?

Tags: mobile, viewport, screen-size

I am developing a website (mostly) without responsive adaptations. I made it so that it looks the same on PC as on smartphone (smartphone-first approach). No frameworks or anything, just nice clean html/css. I specifically made it to fit within 700px width, so that I only need to declare viewport 700px wide and it would fit - but it does not.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="700, initial-scale=1" />
```

but whatever I try, the website is always too big on the smartphone (tested on android, brave and chrome) and has to be zoomed out to get it to fit. How can that be? There is nothing on the page wider than 600px.

here is the site in development https://zugergrafik.ch/betreibungsauszug/

I appreciate any input

Comment: Not sure I'm following exactly. Most mobile devices scale content, and per [MDN], it's normally good to use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` for the values. If you want to control display output, this would be better served with viewport and/or device breakpoints controlling layout in CSS.

Comment: Well, I don´t see why use device-width, that messes everything up and a ton of additional css is needed to fix it. Using Width=700 the page looks perfectly fine, the only thing is that it always gets loaded at about 130% size and the user has to zoom out. And I do not understand why, because the page is made for 700px width.